# Secure mobile only php/html page via client phone#

Tags: php, ios, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile, https

I was asked the following question by a friend to which I believe the answer will be "no way to do it", but it's possible its just beyond my expertise to accomplish or find a working answer:

If someone wanted to make a web page(s) specifically for mobile devices (smart phones only), is it possible through PHP or other Server Side Language to control the privileges & page(s) access by somehow querying the devices cell phone# or IMEI number or any other ID# that can be queried which is (generally) hard coded to the device?

In the absence of a server side option, what minimum components (App, SSL Certificate, magic token, gift from god....) could be installed with user permission that could control access and permissions granted to a smart phone user visiting the secured page?

(Before finishing the question I called my buddy and asked him to explain in more detail what he is thinking: - He wants to sell a service being sold in the field by sales staff where sales people in the field access a sign up page via smart phones only. Instead of using a user name password system he wants to have the server maintain a list of approved cellular numbers (the employee numbers) that is queried and compared on each visit to web page(s) by mobile devices. Thus if a sales agent is let go or quits the approved cellular number is deleted and thus they no longer have access. Also eliminates need to remember/maintain user name/passwords in his view)

any ideas?

Comment: Any client-side solution for reporting mobile numbers etc will not be secure - anyone could write a script that pretends to be any IMEI / Phone number / etc they want to the server.

Comment: @NickJohnson i get that, but i think his thoughts are that this would be a small group involved and the security method he proposes wouldn't be put out there to the public or the sales team for that matter. Just not likely it would be on the hacker hit list radar since the access URL wouldn't be part of any publicized url. (Not that any of this is fool proof, I was just asking the question on his behalf)

Comment: Relying on obscurity is the very definition of bad security. And it would be trivial for a potential attacker to determine what URL your app is fetching!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but not with a simple, browser-based web app.  You will need to wrap the web app with some native code and use something like PhoneGap to bridge between the two.

http://phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mobile detection script to do it. It's going to be a bit difficult otherwise. This is the PHP script I use for detection and it works quite well. I've been using it for a couple of years now. Here is sample code showing how you can use it. It should do what you want by limiting it to mobile devices/smart phones. So for example you can allow access if it detects mobile or show an access denied page if not on mobile. Easy to implement this.

http://mobiledetect.net/

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Exclude tablets.
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){

}

if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){

}

// Alternative method is() for checking specific properties.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->is('Chrome')
$detect->is('iOS')
$detect->is('UC Browser')
// [...]

// Batch mode using setUserAgent():
$userAgents = array(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Desire HD Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19',
'BlackBerry7100i/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/103',
// [...]
);
foreach($userAgents as $userAgent){

  $detect->setUserAgent($userAgent);
  $isMobile = $detect->isMobile();
  $isTablet = $detect->isTablet();
  // Use the force however you want.

}

// Get the version() of components.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->version('iPad'); // 4.3 (float)
$detect->version('iPhone') // 3.1 (float)
$detect->version('Android'); // 2.1 (float)
$detect->version('Opera Mini'); // 5.0 (float)
// [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, he was looking for a level greater than that which you proposed by being able to query ANY permanent serial number or device id number of the specific authorized phones... such as a MAC address (Which I know you can do through http or remotely).

Comment: ** So sorry, that should have said (.... Which I know you  CANT  do through http or remotely) **